# Conditional anchor in structure url

Tags: url, structure, conditional

I have a structure section, where the last child should be an anchor in the slug:

`parent/parent#child`

I'm trying to setup conditional url formats on nested entries as such:

`{parent.uri}{% if object.getDescendants().total() != 0 %)/{% else %}#{% endif %}{slug}`

I've also tried the simpler

`{parent.uri}{% if object.hasDescendants %)/{% else %}#{% endif %}{slug}`

but keep getting stuck tasks when re-saving entries. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: What error is causing the tasks to get stuck?  It'll be logged in `craft/storage/runtime/logs`.

Comment: there's a lot in the craft.log, something like this? `[error] [application] Encountered an error running task 18 (ResaveElements), step 2 of 39: An exception was thrown while trying to save the Entry with the ID “19”: Unexpected ")" in "{{object.parent.uri|raw}}{% if object.getDescendants().total() != 0 %)/{% else %}#{% endif %}{{object.slug|raw}}" at line 1.`

Comment: Argh! I see my mistake right after I press submit. Fixed the typo and now all is good. Not sure how this has evaded me for so long yesterday...

Answer (score 2):

There was a typo hidden in there, otherwise the logic works. To get children as anchors in a structure, the following should do the trick:

`{parent.uri}{% if object.getDescendants().total() != 0 %}/{% else %}#{% endif %}{slug}`

Comment: There's also the slightly less verbose `{parent.uri}{{ object.getDescendants().total() != 0 ? '/' : '#' }}{slug}`